# problem with procedure choose_org, i can't see list of value always when i open the forms

Tags: oracleforms

I'm new in oracle forms. I have a form and when i open the form i see LOV (pre-filter)to choose organization, and after all informations of forms. But when i try to open this form again i don't see this LOV. i don\t understand why. I used fnd_org.choose_org
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nixst.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDJ1N.jpg)

I don't know if problem with a cash of forms

Comment: What exactly do you not see? Is it the field itself? Or is list of values *empty* once you open it? I don't know what FND_ORG.CHOOSE_ORG is (someone else might, though). Did you run form in debug mode and trace its execution?

Comment: i have oracle ebs, and i need to filtr all informations for organization_id and responsability, before open the form. But this procedure standard  FND_ORG.CHOOSE_ORG open list of organization only first time when l open form, and when l whant to open again l dont see this List. i dont know why

Comment: I never used EBS, sorry. Does documentation (related to FND_ORG.CHOOSE_ORG) reveals some information? Is its query accessible to you (i.e. can you *debug* it)?